# Is there a name for this relation: for all $x$ there is $y$ such that $xRy$, and for all $x,y,z$, if $xRy$ and $xRz$, then $y=z$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Suppose for all $x$ there is $y$ such that $xRy$, and for all $x,y,z$, if $xRy$ and $xRz$, then $y=z$.

Does there exist such a binary relation $R$ on some set such that the above properties are satisfied by $R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One set of examples is functions from $A$ to $B$.  For this let $xRy$ mean that $(x,y) \in f$ [using the "function as ordered pairs" formulation]. Then your first requirement expresses that $f$ produces an output $f(x)$ for each $x$ in $A,$ while your second expresses that $f$ is a function.

There may be more  examples.

Edit: In usual math terminology, the term "function" implies it is "single valued". That is, a single input doesn't map to more than one output. That's what your second condition expresses. The first condition really says each element of the domain $A$ maps to *at least*one thing in $B$ [the "codomain"].

There is a version of a so-called "partial function" for which not every element of domain needs to map to something in codomain. [I've seen that more used by logicians]

Comment: I see, so the second condition says that R is well-defined?

Comment: @mdryizk I added something to clarify this issue. I think well-defined is more often used when one works with a definition where it isn't clear one gets a unique output because one takes a representative in the definition. Like when defining the sum of two residue cases mod $n$ by selecting one from each, then adding as usual, then taking class of result.

Comment: Aren't the two requirements precisely the definition of a function, so there cannot be any more examples?

Comment: @Rahul On thinking about it, I agree no more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Define a relation $\operatorname{R}$ on $\Bbb{Z}$ such that  $x\operatorname{R}y$ if and only if  $x+y=0$,where '$+$' denotes the usual addition.